# Getting SVG plus symbol to appear to the right of tab, not the right of the containing div

Tags: css

So I've got a problem where I've got two tabs (https://codepen.io/databell/pen/LYjxvyx) where the first tab opens up content and the second opens up a modal.

Now to be clear, those functions work. That's not the issue. So for those purposes, I deleted those out of my example. Focusing on CSS here.

My problem is I want plus + symbols to appear to the right side of each tab (really a div) and instead one tab has the symbol to the far right of the container, even though the tab is set to width 100%. So I'm stumped as to what the problem is.

This is meant to go into a Shopify store using the Dawn theme, so I'm using their elements here to create this interface.

Here's the code.

```
<div id="info-additions" class="product__accordion accordion info-additions-content" >
          <details>
            <summary>
              <div class="summary__title info-additions-tab g-flex">
                <h2 class="h4 accordion__title t-body benefits">
                  Tab One
                  <span></span>
                </h2>
              </div>
              <div class="summary__title info-additions-tab g-flex">
              <modal-opener class="product-popup-modal__opener no-js-hidden" data-modal="#PopupModal-ingr">
              <button id="ProductPopup-ingr" class="summary__title t-body ingredients" type="button" aria-haspopup="dialog" data-additions-tab="ingredients"> 
                <h2 class="h4 accordion__title">
                  Tab Two
                  <span></span>
                </h2>
              </button>
              </modal-opener>
              </div>
            </summary>
            <div class="accordion__content rte">
              <p>Content</p>
            </div>
          </details>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
*, ::before, ::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
.h0, .h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
    letter-spacing: .06rem;
    line-height: 1.3;
}
.h4, h4 {
   font-size: 1.6rem;
}
.grid {
    list-style: none;
}
.g-flex {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.accordion summary {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 1.5rem 0;
}
.accordion__title {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: calc(100% - 6rem);
    min-height: 1.6rem;
    margin: 0;
    word-break: break-word;
}
details > * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.accordion__title {
    word-break: break-word;
}
.accordion .summary__title {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}
#info-additions {
    clear: both;
    height: auto;
    margin: 15px 0 0;
    border-top: 2px solid;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    width: 100%;
}
.info-additions-content {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    transition: .6s var(--a-cubic-1);
}
.info-additions-tab {
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.info-additions-tab span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    top: 13px;
    right: 2rem;
}
.info-additions-tab button {
    position: relative;
    padding: 16px 0!important;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: left;
}
.info-additions-tab button.benefits {
    width: 50%;
}
.info-additions-tab .product-popup-modal__opener {
    width: 100% !important;
}
.info-additions-tab button.ingredients {
    width: 100%;
}
.info-additions-tab span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    top: 13px;
    right: 2rem;
 }
.info-additions-tab span:before,
.info-additions-tab span:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
    width: 2px;
    height: 18px;
    background-color: black;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.info-additions-tab button:not(.active) span:after {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
}
.info-additions-content {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    transition: 0.6s var(--a-cubic-1);
}
.info-additions-content [data-additions-content] {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: 0.3s 0s;
}
.info-additions-content [data-additions-content].active {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
#info-additions button {
    padding: 0;
    background: transparent;
    color: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want an absolute element like + to stay in the parent element you have to set the position of the parent to "relative".
you have two problems. summary__title doesn't have a position so + doesn't stay in it .
for the second tab, your modal button has a relative position that makes the + stay inside of it instead of the summary__title.

```
.accordion .summary__title {
  ...
  position: relative; // add position
}
#info-additions button {
  ...
  position: unset; // unset the position of the button
}
```

Comment: That worked. The only problem I seem to have left is the text in the first tab is off kilter and not level with everything else.

Comment: @AdamBell there is a 16px padding vertical on your second tab modal button. add that to your first tab h2 with another class

Comment: Yes, I figured that out shortly after posting that. All good now.